# Bash script to search string close to another string in vim (?)

Tags: bash, vim

I'm looking for a (bash) command to open a file (like in vim), search for a specific string, and search backwards from there, to find a second string, and output (only) that second string.
For a file like this:

```
...
aaa x
...
aaa y
...       <-- any number of lines, but necessarily greater than 0
bbb
...
```

I've come up with this so far:
`vim -c "/bbb" -c "n" -c "?aaa" -c "n"`

This doesn't work; vim reads:

```
Error detected while processing command line:
E163: There is only one file to edit
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I also need to save the string `aaa y` into a file/variable -- I can't figure out how.

TIA

Comment: Do you really need Vim for that? Other tools seem more appropriate.

Comment: Also, what you are trying to do is not clear, please edit your question for adding details on how `bbb` is related to `aaa`

Comment: @Fravadona, not sure what I'm missing. I've edited it to be a little more clear. Also, which other tools might seem appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

To address your main question… the commands executed in `-c` parameters are Ex commands, not normal mode commands. It just so happens that `:/` and `:?` are valid Ex commands and work *vaguely* like their normal mode counterparts `/` and `?`, but `:n` is shorthand for `:help :next`:

```
Edit [count] next file.
```

which is *very* different from normal mode `:help n`.

---

But why are you doing that in Vim to begin with? It doesn't seem appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, `vim` may not be the best tool for what you want to achieve.

You can try :

```
#!/bin/bash

expect <<EOF
spawn vim input-file
send ":1\r/bbb\rn\r?aaa\r:.+1,\$ d\r:1,.-1d\r:w! output-file\r"
sleep 1
EOF
```